# why is my PHP query displaying blank results

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables

my query is echoing the right amount of results in my selection box but theyre all blank? super confused any help appreciated

```
<?php
session_start();
$cupsession = $_SESSION['c_cname'];
$teamSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT cup_name FROM teams WHERE cup_name='$cupsession'");
?>



<select name="team-1" required>
        <option value='Holder' disabled selected>Team 1</option> <!--Placeholder for Select-->
          <?php
              while($rows = $teamSet->fetch_assoc()){ //Fills select with cup entries in db
                $teamName = $rows['team_name'];
                echo "  <option value='$teamName'>$teamName</option>";
              }
          ?>
        </select>
```

Comment: `SELECT cup_name` - `$rows['team_name']` you don't select `team_name` so it can't be displayed

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you're trying to get the team_name from your database not cup_name so it would be:

```
$teamSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT team_name FROM teams WHERE cup_name='$cupsession'");
```